# Hidden div will not show on click - Javascript, no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, button, hide

Just like my description says.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDP5Z/1/)

```
<div id="step2" class="question">
    <p>Step two:</p>
    <div id="resultOne" class="script">
        <p>"Test Yes!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="resultTwo" class="script">
        <p>"Test No"</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above div isn't responding to button clicks. It seems like the corresponding JS function isn't even being called.

I know it's probably a minor syntax error, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Where Do you assign the click handler?

Comment: There is no element with the ID `divShow` and `divHide`? And you're also not using the passed arguments? Are you perhaps mixing things up?

Comment: Where are `divShow`, `divHide`, and `divReveal`?

Answer (score 1):

I could not get it to work in the fiddle, it said that the nextStep function was not available.
But this definition of nextStep should work:

```
function nextStep(divShow, divHide, divReveal) {
    var show = document.getElementById(divShow);
    var hide = document.getElementById(divHide);
    var reveal = document.getElementById(divReveal);
    show.style.display = "inline-block";
    hide.style.display = "none";
    if (reveal.style.display == "none") 
        reveal.style.display = "block";
}
```

And change your buttons to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:nextStep('resultOne', 'resultTwo', 'step2')">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:nextStep('resultTwo', 'resultOne', 'step2')">No</button>
```

Notice that the " are gone around the parameters in the getElementById call? What you were trying to get was the element named divShow, not the one referenced to by the content of the variable.

Comment: Ah, I see. What you said makes a lot of sense, but it still doesn't seem to be working for me. I feel like this isn't the correct way to go about using a button to make a div visible/invisible

Comment: Your method would indeed not scale very well. I am however not sufficiently well versed in DOM usage to guide to you a better solution. But we can try to make the one you have working - for a start. If you look in the javascript debug console, what error does it give?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to use the debug console. Do you mean the one in my web browser (FF) or is there in in JSFiddle?

Comment: In FF. And I can't help you with the FF debug console - in Chrome I just press F12 and presto there it is (after opening the Console tab).

Comment: I have it open, but it isn't responding to anything I do in JSFiddle

Comment: It might won't work properly with JSFiddle out of the box. As the other answer says you have to do some "magic" to make it work properly. Although the console in Chrome did work with JSFiddle just fine.

Comment: You might try to put it all together in a html-file and just opening it directly in the browser...

Comment: My original code is actually in a single html file, but I can't seem to find what changes I need to make to get it to work. I think I might just try to learn more about Jquery, which I guess I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the function isn't called because jsfiddle wraps your javascript in an anonymous function that executes on window load. That means the scope of the function you declared is only within that function.

Instead, try attaching it as a global function

```
window.nextStep = function (divShow, divHide, divReveal) {
    var show = document.getElementById(divShow);
    var hide = document.getElementById(divHide);
    var reveal = document.getElementById(divReveal);
    show.style.display = "inline-block";
    hide.style.display = "none";
    if (reveal.style.display == "none") 
        reveal.style.display = "block";
}
```